# What technology / method is used to compile Java on the fly ? [video included]

Tags: java, compilation, on-the-fly

I was watching Notch code Minicraft for the Ludum Dare competition on [this twitch VOD](http://sv.twitch.tv/notch/b/302867302?t=6h15m40s) and I wonder : what does he use to make the changes he makes in the code take effect instantly in the running instance of the game ?

[Twitch link again (@6hours15minutes40seconds)](http://sv.twitch.tv/notch/b/302867302?t=6h15m40s)

Comment: You could try asking him directly on Twitter: https://twitter.com/notch

Comment: Off the top of my head: sounds like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/)

Comment: It might just be the regular Java debugger code reloading though.

Comment: @JesseWebb I actually tried that a few months back, he didn't answer!

Comment: From 2010: [Reloading Java Classes: HotSwap and JRebel — Behind the Scenes](http://java.dzone.com/articles/reloading-java-classes-401) by Dave Booth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse includes a feature called [hot swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping#Software), which is used when you press the debug button to run your application.

While you application is running in that mode, you can make changes to the code, save it, and the new code will be swapped in for the old code (if it does not have any errors).